# How can I declare individual PMOD pins as input or output in an FPGA?

Tags: fpga, verilog, system-verilog, constraints

I have a [Xilinx Basys 3](https://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/1-54wqge.html) demo' board, which contains the Xilinx Artix-7 XC7A35T-1CPG236C FPGA.

I want to use the board's PMOD header as an SPI master interface. Most of the pins are outputs, but MISO is an input. Therefore part of the PMOD pins need to be outputs, and one of them an input.

Given the constraints below, which declare a Basys 3 PMOD header:

```
...
#Pmod Header JA
#Sch name = JA1
set_property PACKAGE_PIN J1 [get_ports {JA[0]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA[0]}]
##Sch name = JA2
set_property PACKAGE_PIN L2 [get_ports {JA[1]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA[1]}]
##Sch name = JA3
set_property PACKAGE_PIN J2 [get_ports {JA[2]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA[2]}]
#Sch name = JA4
set_property PACKAGE_PIN G2 [get_ports {JA[3]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA[3]}]
#Sch name = JA7
set_property PACKAGE_PIN H1 [get_ports {JA[4]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA[4]}]
#Sch name = JA8
set_property PACKAGE_PIN K2 [get_ports {JA[5]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA[5]}]
#Sch name = JA9
set_property PACKAGE_PIN H2 [get_ports {JA[6]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA[6]}]
#Sch name = JA10
set_property PACKAGE_PIN G3 [get_ports {JA[7]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA[7]}]
...
```

And given the following top module in SystemVerilog:

```
module top_module(
    input   wire [7:0]  JA,
);
    ...
endmodule
```

How can I declare individual JA pins as input or output? E.g. to declare `JA[7:3]` as input and `JA[2:0]` as output. Something like:

```
module top_module(
    input   wire [7:3]  JA,
    output  wire [2:0]  JA,
);
    ...
endmodule
```

Comment: I've moved the answer you posted to a question because it appears that it's an edit to the question. If not I can redact it. Please post an actual question in your post for people to answer

Comment: @VoltageSpike I don't understand this very well. You mean that the original question is not an actual question? With regards to the answer, it is indeed an answer since I have tested it and it works. And it can be extended to declare any number of PMOD pins separately to set them as input or output independently, so it answers the original question right away. I will wait for a further explanation or I move the EDIT to a response back again.

Comment: @Martel - I guess the issue detected by *Voltage Spike* is that your "answer" contained an implied invitation for people to reply, so it looks like a question again. Questions are not allowed in an answer. That breaks the whole "Q & A are written in different places" Stack Exchange approach. Since you asked the original question then, if you write an answer, it must be the final solution (i.e. not another question) & you should accept an answer (e.g. yours) to indicate your problem is solved. || So yes, you can write your own answer, but only if you accept one so it's clear the topic is closed

Comment: Added: I see that you only asked your question yesterday. There is a system-imposed delay of 48 hours before a [self-answer](/help/self-answer) can be áccepted. This complicates things a little, but overall as I explained in my comment above - you can write an answer, but since you also asked the question, any answer from you must clearly be the final solution & must avoid any appearance of being another question. In this case, due to that 48 hour restriction, then in any answer you post before 2022-10-24 at 15:24 UTC please make it clear that it is the final solution & áccept it when you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to split `JA` into 2 different ports (notice the **JA1**):

```
#Pmod Header JA
#Sch name = JA1
set_property PACKAGE_PIN J1 [get_ports {JA[0]}]
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA[0]}]
##Sch name = JA2
set_property PACKAGE_PIN L2 [get_ports {JA[1]}]
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA[1]}]
##Sch name = JA3
set_property PACKAGE_PIN J2 [get_ports {JA[2]}]
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA[2]}]
#Sch name = JA4
set_property PACKAGE_PIN G2 [get_ports {JA[3]}]
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA[3]}]
#Sch name = JA7
set_property PACKAGE_PIN H1 [get_ports {JA1[0]}]
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA1[0]}]
#Sch name = JA8
set_property PACKAGE_PIN K2 [get_ports {JA1[1]}]
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA1[1]}]
#Sch name = JA9
set_property PACKAGE_PIN H2 [get_ports {JA1[2]}]
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA1[2]}]
#Sch name = JA10
set_property PACKAGE_PIN G3 [get_ports {JA1[3]}]
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA1[3]}]
```

And then:

```
module top_module(
    input   wire [3:0]  JA1,
    output  wire [3:0]  JA,
);
    ...
endmodule
```

This can be extended to any number of individual pins.